# Positivity of a complex quadratic form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quadratic-forms

This should have a very simple intuitive explanation but I am not able to quite get it right now. Consider $z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ where $z_0, z_3 \ge 0$. Suppose that

$$ z_0 + \lambda z_1 + \bar{\lambda}z_2 + \lambda\bar{\lambda} z_3 \ge 0 \quad \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \, ,$$

where the bar indicates complex conjugation.

Now, why is it immediately clear that $z_1 = \bar{z}_2$?

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by $z_0,z_3>0$ ? That they are real positive numbers ?

Comment: There is no order in $\;\Bbb C\;$ compatible with the one on the reals, so there are no positive or negative complex numbers.

Comment: @quasi As far as I know, that is not a widely accepted, standard used agreement. And $\;p-q\in\Bbb R\iff \text{Im}\,p=\text{Im}\,q\;$ , which is a rather harsh condition which should, imo, at least clearly stated.

Comment: @DonAntonio -- I agree, it should be stated. But in this context, I would assume that $z \ge 0$ means $z$ is real and nonnegative.

Comment: @quasi Eventhough you're a relatively new member of this site, perhaps by you could already know that many, many askers fail into very, very basic mistakes, and thinking the complex numbers in general can be positive, negative and/or one greater than other is a rather common one. If the OP doesn't state it **clearly**, I wouldn't assume he knows what is going on.

Comment: The equation is probably from a book, hence the OP's question as to why it should be "obvious".

Comment: The answer is trivial. Yes, the ordering means what is stated by @quasi and I think that is quite common to assume.

Comment: @quasi It is indeed from a book on operator algebra. The context here is the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in a $*$-algebra.

Comment: @J.Rahman -- What book, what page?

Comment: @quasi Cf. [Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 1](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540170938) Lemma 2.3.10 (p.49).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $\lambda=1\,$ yields $z_1 + z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $\text{Im}(z_1)=-
\text{Im}(z_2)$.

Setting $\lambda=i\,$ yields $i(z_1 - z_2) \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $\text{Re}(z_1)=
\text{Re}(z_2)$.

Therefore $z_1=\bar{z_2}$.

Comment: I still succeeded to see briefly the deleted comments. It seems there are no more doubts to this.

Comment: @DonAntonio -- yes, all resolved -- thanks.